# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable (while not using a function)

Tags: python

I have this error when executing my code. I looked around on other posts about this, but all these posts mention the use of `()` or `[]` where they should not be used. However, in my case I do not see that being the issue as the only thing I am trying to do is overwrite the value of an index of one list with another item of another list. This is the code I am trying to call it in:

```py
def reproduce(boardx, boardy, nqueens):
    boardChild = [-1] * nqueens
    n = random.randint(0, nqueens - 1) #percentage of how much of one parent is reproduced and how much of the other parent
    d = 0
    for d in range(n): # the first n part of parent x
        boardChild[d] = boardx[d]

    s = d + 1
    for s in range(nqueens - 1): # the last n-(len(board)-1) part of parent y
        boardChild[s] = boardy[s]

    return boardChild
```

Python currently only gives an error about this line:

```py
boardChild[s] = boardy[s]
```

but not the similar line in the loop above it. This is how I call the function (`population[j]` and `population[k]` are lists for reference):

```py
childx = population[j].copy
childy = population[k].copy
child = reproduce(childx, childy, nqueens)
```

I also tried to find out if any of the used variables were known functions, but that does not seem to be true either. I am completely lost with this one. Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Calling `copy` won't help you in any significant way. A copy of `population[j]` will contain new references to the same objects referenced by `population[j]`, which you then assign directly into `boardChild`. You probably want `deepcopy`.

Comment: "all these posts mention the use of () or [] where they should not be used" yes, that's the same problem as in your code; the error message can only effectively mean one thing. The error occurs when you try to do `boardChild[s] = boardy[s]`; this tells you that either `boardChild` or `boardy` is a function. `boardChild` clearly has a local assignment that isn't a function, so it must be `boardy`, which was passed in. So you look at where the value came from, and discover that you have a typo.

Comment: "I also tried to find out if any of the used variables were known functions, but that does not seem to be true either." How did you try? Did you try, for example, `print(type(boardy))`? When you looked at the code where you called the function, did you try checking the value of `childx` and `childy` in between assigning them and calling the function?

Comment: "My compiler currently only gives an error about this line: " The `TypeError`s *don't occur at compile time*, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
childx = population[j].copy
childy = population[k].copy
```

If you are trying to use the copy method of a list, this will not do that. You are accessing the method, but not calling it so `childx` and `childy` are functions.

I admit I am not sure why the first loop doesn't raise this error though.

Comment: "I admit I am not sure why the first loop doesn't raise this error though." Well, sometimes `n` will be `0`. It might also be that on some runs, it did cause an error, and OP simply didn't notice that the error was happening there first on that run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your variable *boardy* seems to be a variable. If you change that variable name to anything else it should work fine. Something like:

```
def reproduce(boardX, boardY, nqueens):

boardChild = [-1] * nqueens
n = random.randint(0, nqueens - 1) #percentage of how much of one parent is reproduced and how much of the other parent
d = 0
for d in range(n): # the first n part of parent x
    boardChild[d] = boardX[d]

s = d + 1
for s in range(nqueens - 1): # the last n-(len(board)-1) part of parent y
    boardChild[s] = boardY[s]

return boardChild
```